# Как вывести медиану трех чисел с использованием return в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В основной программе пользователь вводит три числа, которые передаются в качестве параметров в функцию. Функция должна вернуть медиану трёх чисел, т. е. среднее из этих чисел. Например, среди чисел 4, 6, 2 медианой является число 4. Среди чисел 5 4 5 медианой является 5.

Есть маленький кусочек кода

```
a = int(input(""))
b = int(input(""))
c = int(input(""))

def kuk(a , b , c):

kuk(a , b , c)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = int(input(""))
b = int(input(""))
c = int(input(""))

def kuk(a , b , c):
  return sorted([a, b, c])[1]

kuk(a , b , c)
```

Источник https://tproger.ru/translations/python-sorting/

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа такого будет:

```
print(sorted([a, b, c])[1])
```

Делаем список из введённых чисел, сортируем его, берём 2-й элемент (по индексу 1, поскольку в Python адресация элементов начинается с нуля, как обычно и в других языках)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А как это провернуть, не прибегая к сортировке? Как сделать это, используя def и return?

Comment: @ВиталийАлександров Ну вам как-то надо будет числа отранжировать, чтобы найти медиану. if хотя бы можно использовать?

Comment: Медиана для нечётного числа элементов последовательности - это серединный элемент после её сортировки, так что вам придётся делать сортировку тем или иным способом. Можно с помощью if или min/max извратиться, но как-то это странно.

Comment: Спасибо, сделаю как вы посоветовали

Comment: @ВиталийАлександров В соседнем ответе дали полный код, я то просто заготовку дал, хотя и раньше :)